# How do I find the equation of a straight line passing through a point and parallel to a line?

Tags: calculus

Find the equation of a straight lines passing through point (0, 1) and parallel to the line 2y-x+6=0.

Comment: If you post your work, people will be more inclined to give a hint or answer your question.

Comment: I just find maths really difficult so trying to begin answering this question is where I get stuck. I know it has something to do with Ax+By+C=0 but I don't understand how to get to the answer.

Comment: Explaining your thoughts really helps! I had roughly the same idea as Anmol, so you can read his answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two lines to be parallel they must have the same slope.

Also you can make use of the fact that the family of lines parallel to a given line(Say $L_1$) is of the form $L_1+K=0$  where K is any constant.

Thus lines parallel to $$2y-x+6=0$$ are $$2y-x+6+k=0$$
Now for line through (0,1): $2(1)-(0)+6+k=0$ which gives $k=-8$.

Thus the line comes out to be $$2y-x-2=0$$ or $$2y-x=2$$

Comment: Thank you so much! Is it the same principle (+k) for straight lines perpendicular to another line?

Comment: Yes in that case family of lines parellel to a line $L:y=mx+c$ is given by $L':x+my=k$. K being the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: we have the line $$y=mx+n$$ from $$2y+6-x=0$$ we get $$m=\frac{1}{2}$$ and form
$$1=0+n$$ we get $n=1$